# Most idiomatic way of writing and reading an array at the same time

Tags: io, go, goroutine

I have one array that gets modified a few times per second with one goroutine. In another function, I read a random value from the array once every few seconds. What would be the most Go-like way of approaching this problem?

In Java, for example, I would lock the array first and then read from it. I'm not sure if I could use channels for this because I don't want to wait until my other function reads before I can continue updating the array.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const (
    SliceLength = 32
)

var mySlice []int

func randInt(min int, max int) int {
    return min + rand.Intn(max-min)
}

func writeSlice() {
    for index, _ := range mySlice {
        mySlice[index] = rand.Intn(100)
    }
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    mySlice = make([]int, SliceLength)

    // First time just to populate it.
    writeSlice()

    // Write to the slice.
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(randInt(10, 50)) * time.Millisecond)
            writeSlice()
        }
    }()

    // Read from slice.
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(randInt(1, 5)) * time.Second)
        fmt.Println(mySlice[randInt(0, SliceLength)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutex [`sync.RWMutex`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) can work here. You simply share your slice between two goroutines, locking and releasing before/after each slice operation.

Whilst you're exploring possibilities, you should also consider what the "**[shared-nothing](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#sharing)**" principle would mean. You would want to find a solution that does not use a mutex and in which each goroutine has private data only - shared-nothing.

Suppose you had a third goroutine. Think of it as a server. It holds the slice (or any other contended data structure as required). When your first goroutine wants to make a change, it sends a message on a channel to the server, saying "change x to y". When your second goroutine wants to read the data, it might simply read a copy of the data off a channel coming from the server.

Inside the server, a select statement will choose between incoming update messages and outgoing read messages - bear in mind that the guards can be on either channel inputs or channel outputs, so this is easy to do.

```
...  declare and initialise the slice
for {
    select {
    case instruction = <-update:
        ...  apply the instruction to the slice
    case output<- slice:
        ...  sent the slice to the consumer
    }
}
```

Notice that the server code is itself *single-threaded*, i.e. there is no shared-memory access to the slice, even though the behaviour overall is concurrent. This is a nice feature of the CSP approach: locally, there is never any need to worry about shared access to data. "Shared-nothing" means what it says.

Furthermore, you can fully reason about the possible states of such a piece of code locally, without needing global knowledge. This is a BIG benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`sync.RWMutex`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex).

> An RWMutex is a reader/writer mutual exclusion lock. The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer. RWMutexes can be created as part of other structures; the zero value for a RWMutex is an unlocked mutex.

Comment: If I use RWMutex, how would I call it? `mutex := sync.RWMutex`, then just `mutex.Lock()`, write to the slice, and then `mutex.Unlock()`? How will it know to lock my slice?

Comment: Also, what's the difference between `sync.Mutex` and `sync.RWMutex`?